# Програма предназначена для удаления общих елементов,но не понимаю почему не работает

Tags: python, list

```
q = 1
n = 1
firstFold = []
secondFold = []
while n > 0:
    if q == 1:
        x = input("Enter number to first folder: ")
        if x == "stop":
            q = 2
        else:
            firstFold.append(x)
    else:
        y = input("Enter number to second folder: ")
        if y == "stop":
            break
        else:
            secondFold.append(y)
for elem in firstFold:
    if elem in secondFold:
        firstFold.remove(elem)
        secondFold.remove(elem)
result = firstFold + secondFold
print(result)
```

Comment: Вы итерируетесь по списку, из которого удаляете элементы. Если в списке будут повторяющиеся элементы, возможны неожиданные эффекты связанные с таким удалением.

Comment: Может, Вам нужен `set(foldername)` для удаления повторяющихся элементов? Например: `print([1,2,3,2])#>>>[1,2,3,2,2,2]`  `print(set[1,2,3,2,2,2])#>>>{1,2,3}` — функция `set()` оставила один элемент `2`, так, как он повторяется.

Answer (score 1):

Всё работает:

```
Enter number to first folder: 1
Enter number to first folder: 2
Enter number to first folder: stop
Enter number to second folder: 2
Enter number to second folder: 3
Enter number to second folder: stop
['1', '3']
```